# nethermind node stuck at syncing states 96.5%

Tags: nethermind

I have started syncing an eth node using nethermind, and initially, the state sync process was increasing by 1% every 10 minutes (in average) and it was downloading 1200kb/s of states data. Now that the syncing is 96.5% done the node syncing process has slowed down significantly. Now it takes 24 hours per percentage, and it is downloading an average of 10kb/s of data.

Anyone knows the reason?

Answer (score 1):

When you get close to 100% then you start syncing the data that is changing most rapidly and if your IO is not fast enough, then the data may be moving forward faster than you can sync it from other nodes.

Many of the edge cases of the Nethermind fat sync are described here:
https://docs.nethermind.io/nethermind/ethereum-client/sync-modes